# inspector feeze blue box

Tags: css, firefox-developer-tools

Firefox 46.0.1.  I'm using the inspector.  I'm a beginner.  When I move the mouse around, I get a blue box around the element.  I would like to stop the movement so I can use my mouse to move about the lower info boxes.

I found a way of doing this before, but cannot find it now via google.  I know this wasn't done via a breakpoint.  It was some key press.

answer:
Ok, click on the box with arrow in it; it's on the upper left margin. It turns blue. Move mouse to where you want.  Left click.  The blue box goes away, but the text below stays frozen.

Supposedly, the answer is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Select_an_element

Robert

Comment: Try clicking? That would select the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are stuck in is often referred to as "Point to Inspect" mode or "Inspect Element" mode. In many browser developer tools, this mode is entered via application menu item, right click context menu, or a button in the developer tools UI.  The idea is to help the user see the hovered element in a DOM tree visualization.

Usually, this mode is active until the next left click. When the user left-clicks on an element, it is revealed in the DOM tree view. (Some tools also log the element to console.) **So, to get out of the mode, simply click on some element to select it.**